# Phpredis and apache

Tags: php, apache, redis

Is redis compatible with an apache server? I'm trying to run redis from a php script stored in my apache servers web directory.

```
<?php 
//Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
$redis = new Redis(); 
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379); 
echo "Connection to server sucessfully"; 
//check whether server is running or not 
echo "Server is running: ".$redis->ping(); 
?>
```

When I try loading my web page I get a 505 programming error. Does my apache setup even matter? I'm thinking my phpredis extension might not be setup correctly. I'm able to ping redis from the raspberry pi terminal. If that is my issue does anybody have any good tutorials on adding a redis extension to php?

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a `try-catch` block, catching a [`RedisException`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#class-redisexception) to get more information about the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same result, if you use: `$redis = new Redis();` and the extension is not properly installed that would technically prevent any code from running; if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Try running `phpinfo()` under Apache to see if Redis is configured in.

Comment: I checked phpinfo() and didn't find any listings with Redis info.

Comment: If the 505 is coming in the browser then that means "HTTP Version Not Supported"

Comment: I think you are missing the part of Apache configuration where you tell it to add Redis module, specifically the lines beginning `sudo ln -s ...` on this page https://anton.logvinenko.name/en/blog/how-to-install-redis-and-redis-php-client.html

Comment: Ok, my bad I just restarted my systems and now it is throwing a RedisException of "Connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

1. Makre sure you installed that extension...
2. Check https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis
3. Use something like Redis Desktop Manager to easily verify if your redis is running and have nice too see what's inside (if you're on localhost or access via remote is allowed)
4. Read your apache logs, should be around /var/log/ (httpd or apache) on non-windows machine, they should have more detailed info on why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lots of probably beginner mistakes, but I figured it out. I didn't have and still don't have a start up script, so I had to start Redis from the raspberry pi terminal using this command I assume I'm going to need to do this after each restart: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ redis-server. The quickstart guide on the official Redis page gave me the solution https://redis.io/topics/quickstart.

Comment: Use `systemctl` to start Redis for you... https://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-systemd-service-files

Comment: I will have to look into that. It would be really nice, from your link my understanding is that anything I put here: `/etc/systemd/system` gets ran on startup?

Comment: You have to enable it, but yes. It's pretty straightforward. Just read the article through and you'll get it.